# Publish jar to maven local and use this dependency in root project

Tags: java, gradle, clips

Update

I would like to use external library that is not available on maven repository.

Currently, I have subproject called libs and within CLIPSJNI.jar
In Gradle.build of root project I declare dependency like this

```
dependencies {
  implementation files('/libs/library.jar')
}
```

but in order to run java application I also have to add file with .jnilib.

My question is it possible to publish to maven local this jar and reuse this dependency. So that .jnilib is redundant.

Initial question was resolve. If you wanna use CLIPSJNI in java application there are only 2 steps you should follow, which are described in comments down below.

Comment: This worked for me in gradle.build add to your dependencies "implementation files('clips-jni/CLIPSJNI.jar')"

Comment: Don't forget to add libCLIPSJNI.jnilib to your project. Otherwise, library is not found in java path and thus it will fail with following runtime exception java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError.